# Is it possible to change the colour of the launcher/dash "glass"?

Tags: launcher, unity-dash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the background color of the unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81763/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-unity-launcher)

The launcher and dash have a semitransparent background which I think of as being made of black glass. I know you can change the transparency of the launcher (not sure about the dash), but is it possible to change the colour of this glass?

Comment: after further review - this question did technically come first....

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 11.10, the color of the launcher and dash changes to match the color of the desktop wallpaper.