# Why my dash became blue?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Before I re-installed Ubuntu, my Unity Dash had turned blue. what made it turn blue and how do I make it look like that again?

EDIT: According to the comments about being too specific and since I got my answer, I simplified the question.

Comment: try changing your desktop background to same as you had previously.

Comment: Problems with 13.04 are offtopic but ... your dash changes color based on your background.

Comment: I didn't know the background had that effect (also I had forgotten that the background was bugged at the same time it turned blue). I changed to "La Gomera" and it is blue now. Thanks.

Comment: @Rinzwind Should we really close this? (I'm not saying I think you necessarily voted to close it, I just figured you'd have some insight into the matter.) I haven't used Unity much for quite some time. But isn't this color-changing behavior of the dash present in stable versions, too? (And even if not, is it an established feature that will continue to exist in 13.04 through its release date?) Given that this is *answered* and may be helpful to others, and as far as I can tell doesn't seem to really be about 13.04, I don't see a reason to close it.

Comment: It had references that may have made it too specific, since I edited the question I think it should not be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change the background color of the unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81763/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: @EliahKagan well it WILL have a duplicate anyways ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour of your dash is determined by your desktop background. I am forever changing my background which gives a nice fresh feel to the dash each time :)